# MVC is throwing parsing error while validating the input with regular expression for a phone number

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using `^[0-9()- ]+$` as regular expression to validate Phone number. 
Basically I want to allow only **numbers, hypen & both braces i.e. ( )**.

I have added this in the model level attribute (in MVC3.0). 
After giving a valid string (say 5299912548), its accepting, but in the view its throwing error as "**parsing "^[0-9()- ]+$" - [x-y] range in reverse order.**".

Is there a problem in the Regex used or some problem with other MVC3 stuff?

Comment: Check this one - 
[Regex Error: [x-y] range in reverse order][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476922/net-regex-error-x-y-range-in-reverse-order

Comment: Note that this will also allow `(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)(7)(8)(9)(0)`, hardly a standard phone number format, even once it's working as intended.

Answer (score 3):

```
^[0-9()\- ]+$
```

You need to escape the hyphen - it's a range indicator otherwise.

You could also do this:

```
^[0-9() -]+$
```

The hyphen and space have been switched. Hyphen placement in regex has bugged me before, and I sometimes need to shuffle the position in these situations.

If anyone can enlighten me as to why this is, I'd appreciate it.

But this will fix this issue.

**edit:**

Research reveals the answer. Some flavors of regex allow the hyphen to be first or last and still be interpreted literally.

Comment: I dont think that is the problem as I ve another regex as ^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]+$ for allowing alphabates, numbers & hypen. And its working fine there.

Comment: But in that 2nd regex example, the hyphen isn't preceded by a closing bracket :) Have you tried it?

Comment: @Biki, your second expression is working, because the 9 from the range 0-9 is the end of a range and that range can not be the start of a new range, so the regex interpreter knows that that "-" can not belong to a range and so is not throwing an error.

Comment: @HappyTimeGopher, let me try to enlighten you. A hyphen is a special character inside of a regex character classes, so basically you need to escape it to match it literally. There are several places where the interpreter knows, that it can't be a range operator and it is therefor accepted literally without escaping. This is at the start and the end of a character class, like you did it in your second solution. The other places are those directly after a range, like I explained above to Biki (but those shouldn't be used, because it is irritating). But always escaping does not hurt.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this part:

```
[/-.]
```

That means "the range of characters from '/' to '.'" - but '/' comes after '.' in Unicode, so the range makes no sense.

If you wanted it to mean "slash, dash or period" then you want:

```
[/\-.]
```

In other words, you need to escape the dash. Note that if this is in a regular C# string literal, you'll need to perform another level of escaping too:

```
string pattern = "[/\\-.]";
```

Using a verbatim string literal means you don't need to escape the backslash:

```
string pattern = @"[/\-.]";
```

Alternatively, you can just put the dash at the start:

```
[-/.]
```

or end:

```
[/.-]
```