# Regex to allow limited special chars with one alphabet compulsory

Tags: c#, regex, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

Here I have used this regex for atleast one alphabet and rest can be anything else.

```
var regexItem = new Regex("[a-zA-Z]+");
```

Now, in this I want to allow only limited set of special chars:
( ) ! + * _ - , '  " . ?

I am trying with :

```
var regexItem = new Regex("[a-zA-Z0-9()!+*_-,'\".?]");
```

But its now working.

Update: I need regex as at-least on alphabet and limited set of special chars mentioned above, numbers etc will be allowed no restriction on that.

**UPDATE 2**

valid examples:
aaa
aaa13
aa!12
as()!(all given chars)

Invalid:
aaa@
@123
123
aaa123%#^

Thanks

Comment: *"atleast one alphabet and rest can be anything else"* = `[a-zA-Z].*`.

Comment: That will not work on `1a2`. It will fail, but it should match

Comment: What is not working? How isn't it working? Surely you must escape the `-` (and use a verbatim string literal) or put it at the char class end. [**Range in reverse order**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476922/net-regex-error-x-y-range-in-reverse-order)?

Comment: So, tried `var regexItem = new Regex("[a-zA-Z0-9()!+*_,'\".?-]");` yet? Is that working as you expect?

Comment: Please post some sample valid and invalid strings, and specify what should be matched and what not.

Comment: Don't try to write one huge regex. Instead, write two little ones and use `&&`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this RegEx:

```
^(?=.*[A-Za-z])[\w\(\)\!\+\*\-\,\'\"\.\?]*$
```

I think this is what you meant, but your question was not very clear. It will make sure there is at lease one letter using a **Positive Lookahead** (`(?=.*[A-Za-z])`). Then it will select the allowed characters (letters, number and all the special characters you stated) 0 or more times

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/yY0jE0/2)</kbd>

Comment: `\w\d` doesn't make sense in a character class, Because `\w` contains `\d`. *(`\w` = `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)*

Comment: updated question. PS it is windows phone ie c# Regex class

Comment: Actually, without the `RegexOptions.ECMAScript`, `\w` means `[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}_]`.

Comment: This is working: var regexItem = new Regex(@"^(?=.*[A-Za-z])[\w\d\(\)\!\+\*\-\,\'\""\.\?]*$");

Comment: Added space: var regexItem = new Regex(@"^(?=.*[A-Za-z])[\w\d\(\)\!\+\*\-\,\'\""\.\? ]*$");

Comment: @Shafizadeh Yes, I totally forgot!

Comment: `(?=.*[A-Za-z])` lookahead helps me to check the string should contain at least an character